# Raw Output and Input Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I need to move some networkx graphs between different file locations and wondered the best way to do it.

In the reference documentation (https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/convert.html) there's no format that preserves data in the nodes which is crucial for me.

When I try using the `nx.to_dict_of_dicts` method, this doesn't preserve all of the node data either.

Is there a way to convert a graph to a raw form dictionary which can then be copied and pasted into another python script where it can be understood again by the package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pickle for this:

```
import pickle

# Save (serialize)
pickle.dump(graph, open( "graph.p", "wb" ) )

# Load
graph = pickle.load( open( "graph.p", "rb" ) )
```

It will serialize your graph object (save the Python object to disk in binary). Then, you wil be able to load your Python object (here, your networkx graph) from this file.

And there is dedicated functions for this in networkx to:

```
read_gpickle()
write_gpickle()
```

See: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gpickle.html

And in fact networkx provides other options for this use case:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html